# Can cx_Freeze keep a selected import outside of library.zip?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a Python program that reads in some parameters from an external **my_parameters.py** file.
This external file simply assigns some variables to values, for example:

```
# My parameter file
param1 = 3
param2 = 4
```

I am loading this file into the main python program with

```
import my_parameters as mP

# do stuff with ( mP.param1 )  etc...
```

This works as expected. Now I want to package my python program as a standalone .exe file so that the user will not have to separately install all the necessary python libraries.  For this I am using **cx_Freeze**. After invoking the setup.py build process, I get a build directory with my program.exe file and a library containing a very large number of DLL packages, and the .exe does in fact work as expected.

The only problem is that the **my_parameters.py** file that I wanted to be a plain text file that the user can directly edit, has been moved inside the lib/library.zip file, and has also been converted to a compiled format **my_parameters.pyc**

Is there some easy way to get a .exe version of my python program, and yet still be able to load in an external plain-text file like my_parameter.py for easy user configuration?  My quick review of https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html has so far not answered this.

Comment: Not knowing how to solve it that way, I wrote a program to read my file using csv.reader(f, delimiter='='), building up a dictionary with name-value pairs, and then using "from types import SimpleNamespace" and "myDat = SimpeNamespace(**myDict)" to install the variables so I then have myDat.param1, myDat.param2 etc. with values loaded from the file.